# Count (*) rows based on values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

RECORD TABLE

```
record_id  type_id   title
---------  -------   -----
1          1         Title1
2          2         Title2
3          1         Title3
4          2         Title4
```

RECORD VALUES

```
id   record_id   field_id  field_value
--   ---------   --------  -----------
1    1           8         active 
2    2           12        some value
3    1           16        lenght
4    2           3         some value
```

I want to count records FROM record table which `type_id` is = 1 AND FROM record values table `field_id_8` field value = active **AND** `field_id_16` field value = lenght.

Based on the two example table above the query return 1 (`record_id` = 1 is the only one row which fit to query).

I can create simple MYSQL queries but I can't do anything to solve this one. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I cannot see field_id_8 (which is a good thing, I guess)

Comment: @danielbidala Hi, there i think I figured out better way... Look at the bottom of my answer I add final query I hope :)

Comment: You are awesome. All of your solutions worked. This last one is the fastest way.

Comment: There is 297,744 row in record_values table and the query runs 1.18 ms. The prevous one was 5040.07 ms. And in wihich query we used records table runs 278.07 ms. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
OK first time i was misunderstood the question I hope now i figure it right.

If i was right in comment below this should work for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(rt.record_id)) AS COUNTED
FROM record_table rt
INNER JOIN record_values rv
ON rt.record_id = rv.record_id
WHERE rt.type_id = 1 AND 
(8 IN (SELECT rv2.field_id
       FROM record_values rv2
       WHERE rv2.record_id = rt.record_id) AND 
'active' IN (SELECT rv2.field_value
             FROM record_values rv2
             WHERE rv2.record_id = rt.record_id)) AND
 (16 IN (SELECT rv2.field_id
         FROM record_values rv2
         WHERE rv2.record_id = rt.record_id) AND
 'lenght' IN (SELECT rv2.field_value
              FROM record_values rv2
              WHERE rv2.record_id = rt.record_id))
```

Here is sql fiddle for that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7be41/14 so you can check if that's work now...

GL!

**One more edit:**

When you have data like this:

```
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 | id   | record_id | field_id | field_value |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 |  xx  |     7     |    23    |   active    |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 |  xx  |     7     |    16    |   lenght    |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 |  xx  |     7     |    8     |  some value |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 | etc...                                    |
```

Do you want to that data be included and counted or not. If you want to be use the query from the beginning of the answer. if you don't want to be counted use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(rt.record_id)) AS COUNTED
FROM record_table rt
INNER JOIN record_values rv
ON rt.record_id = rv.record_id
WHERE rt.type_id = 1 AND 
8 IN (SELECT rv2.field_id
      FROM record_values rv2
      WHERE rv2.record_id = rt.record_id AND
      rv2.field_value = 'active') AND
16 IN (SELECT rv2.field_id
       FROM record_values rv2
       WHERE rv2.record_id = rt.record_id AND
       rv2.field_value = 'lenght')
```

This query will count only record_id which have two rows in record_values table like this:

```
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 | id   | record_id | field_id | field_value |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 |  xx  |     y     |    8     |   active    |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
 |  xx  |     y     |    16    |   lenght    |
 +------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

Hope this help end you understand the difference between this two query. Here is SQL Fiddle and for this second query so you can play a little with data and see what's happened http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c52bf/2

**NOTE** in second fiddle i change a little data in table to test it so to not be confused...

GL!

**ONE MORE EDIT**

Ups i just realize that there is a better way to solve this. Hope not too late...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM record_values rv
INNER JOIN record_values rv2
ON rv.record_id = rv2.record_id
WHERE rv.field_id = 8 AND rv.field_value = 'active' AND 
      rv2.field_id = 16 AND rv2.field_value = 'lenght'
```

I think this query is more convenient for your problem...

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39725/2) for that...

**NOTE** I add few more value there for testing so **2** is a correct answer in that data set... :)

Comment: Thanks for helping! Yes, you figured it out. It works but I need AND instead of OR in your example. Unfortunatly with AND it doesn't work I don't know why. Any suggestion?

Comment: ouuuu now i see :) basically i don't need at all this part AND field_value = 'active' in WHERE clause because when field_id = 8, filed value is always 'active'.. I'm i right?

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood. When field_id = 8, field_value is not always active and when field_id = 16, field_value is not always lenght. I don't want to modify my database structure. In record table there is basic info about records. In record values table there is all the values filled in the form of the record.

Comment: Ok than we just need to extand this query a little bit and it will work... just give me few minutes :)

Comment: I have one more question before i finish my query so i don't have to edit it again after... Just to be sure and to not misunderstood again. You want to count value where field_value is 'active' in the same row where field_id is 8?

Comment: I want to count individual record_id. In the example: count individual record_id WHERE (field_id = 8 AND field_value = active) AND (field_id = 16 AND field value = lenght) Maybe we don't need record table because record id is in record values table.

Comment: Here i edit it again test it and let me know if that's work :)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. This one seems to work now. Nevertheless I realised we actually don't need record table because field_id 8 and field_id 16 belongs to type_id 1. Another types doesn't use these field id. Maybe without record table the query may look more compact.

Comment: You're welcome. Which query suit to you first or second? Just to make sure, i think, based on your comment, that the second one is what you looking for.

Comment: The second one is working well. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You're welcome :) Also if you are sure that you don't need type_id from RECORD table, you can try this query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c52bf/4 ... GL! P.S. If this answer help you, I would appreciate that if you can mark it as useful... Thanks